# Asynchronous ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, f#

I'm trying to write an asynchronous server that queries a SQL Server database and am concerned that my DB side is too synchronous. Specifically, I can call `ExecuteReader` asynchronously but cannot then call `reader.Item` asynchronously and is where 57% of the time is spent (blocking my precious thread!).

Is this the most asynchronous I can do with ADO.NET or is there an asynchronous way to do `reader.Item` as well?

Comment: I know excatly what you mean - allways wondered why there are no async-methods on (Sql)DataReaders as this should be your classical network-bound operation. Reading the docs it's somewhat hinted that BeginExecuteReader/EndExecuteReader will "retrieves one or more result sets from the server." - so are you sure that most of the time is spent in Read?

Comment: @balexandre: Either. Whichever is most suitable.

Comment: @JonHarrop: as this is in ADO.NET rather than the core .NET libraries, I'd anticipate any solution to be the same for both languages.

Comment: @Carsten König: VS profiler says almost all of the time is spent in `reader.Item`. I've updated the question...

Comment: @Jon Harrop: just the same - sorry I cannot provide any reasonable answer. ... and just as I write this I doublecheck and suddenly find this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223681(v=VS.110).aspx and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223698(v=VS.110).aspx - of course the question is: will this improve your problem when the problem is in Item?

Comment: @CarstenKönig `BeginExecuteReader` and `EndExecuteReader` don't do much. They take care of running the query on a different thread so you don't have to create one yourself.

Comment: @Stijn: "They take care of running the query on a different thread so you don't have to create one yourself". Surely the whole point is that they run the query asynchronously, without blocking any threads?

Comment: @JonHarrop I've removed my answer as I might not fully understand the way it works yet. What exactly are you doing with reader.Item ? Can you edit your question to include sample code?

Comment: @Stijn I think it' rather obvious what Jon does with Item - he reads some values form the reader ....

Comment: @CarstenKönig I'm asking because I don't really understand what is happening. I assume the SqlDataReader runs on a different thread than the current one. Once it's completed, a loop is initiated with `while (reader.Read())` calling `reader.Item` and doing *something* with the data. The only asynchronous action you can do with this is run that *something* on a different thread.

Comment: @Carsten König: Yep, looks like Microsoft's SQL Server API is not properly asynchronous but they're fixing it in .NET 4.5. If you post your comment as an answer I'll choose it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this issue is to be fixed in the next version of the framework:

[DbDataReader.ReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223681%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)
and
[DbDataReader.NextResultAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223698%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)